# discord.js play pulseaudio source

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js, pulseaudio

I want to create a bot, that plays the content of a specified pulseaudio source.

```
const pacat: cp.ChildProcessWithoutNullStreams = cp.spawn("pacat", [
    "-r",
    "-d", "vsink_disc.monitor",
    "--volume", "65536",
    "--format", "s16le"
])

const player = vc?.play(pacat.stdout);
```

But it doesn't work. I've also tried to use ffmpeg (as this guy did https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/1823) for it, and I also don't get any output:

```
const ffmpeg = cp.spawn('ffmpeg', [
    '-f', 'pulse',
    '-i', 'vsink_disc.monitor',
    '-vn',
    '-map', '0:a',
    '-acodec', 'libopus',
    'pipe:1'
]);
```

Comment: What specifically does not work? Are there any errors? And `vc?` is not a valid variable name. Try converting `pacat.stdout` to a buffer with the appropriate mime type and play that; Discord.JS already uses FFMPEG conversion - it supports what FFMPEG does. Try converting it to either a `.mp3` file or a stream/buffer.

Comment: @PiggyPlex vc is the VoiceConnection and the ? is from TypeScript; I do not get any errors, but it dosn't play any sound. How could it convert the stream/socket to a buffer?